# Converting Int to String to display time

Tags: c#, .net, c#-5.0

Help me out with my code. I am trying to convert the `int` to `time` format using the `ToString()` method. When I run it I get 09:100. What can I do more especially using the `getters` and `setters`?

```
public struct Time
{

    public int hours;
    public int minutes;

    public Time(int hh, int mm)
    {
        this.hours = hh;
        this.minutes = mm;
    }

    public int hh { get { return hours; } set { hours = value % 60; } }
    public int mm { get { return minutes; } set { minutes = value % 60; } }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", hh, mm);

    }

    public static implicit operator Time(int t)
    {

        int hours = (int)t / 60;
        int minutes = t % 60;

        return new Time(hours, minutes);

    }

    public static explicit operator int(Time t)
    {

        return t.hours * 60 + t.minutes;
    }
    public static Time operator +(Time t1, int num)
    {

        int total = t1.hh * 60 + t1.mm + num;
        int h = (int)(total / 60) % 24,
            m = total % 60;
        return new Time(h, m);
    }

    public int Minutes { get { return minutes; } set { minutes = value % 60; } }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Time t1 = new Time(9, 30);
            Time t2 = t1;
            t1.minutes = 100;
            Console.WriteLine("The time is: \nt1={0}  \nt2={1} ", t1, t2);
            Time t3 = t1 + 45;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `int` represent?

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense.  Try rephrasing it as a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.  You say that you are running some code.  Are we to guess what that is?  More generally, if you want to output a time format then you would use an object that actually represents time, which means a `TimeSpan` or `DateTime`.  Perhaps it would be logical to convert your `int` to whichever of those is appropriate first and then call `ToString` on that.

Comment: Pardon. I did not know how best to ask the question. Anyway I copied my code onto the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In main method change `t1.minutes = 100;` to `t1.Minutes = 100;`, 
 code will look like :

```
public struct Time
{

private int hours;
private int minutes;

public Time(int hh, int mm)
{
    this.hours = hh;
    this.minutes = mm;
}

public int hh { get { return hours; } set { hours = value % 60; } }
public int mm { get { return minutes; } set { minutes = value % 60; } }

public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", hh, mm);
}

public static implicit operator Time(int t)
{
    int hours = (int)t / 60;
    int minutes = t % 60;
    return new Time(hours, minutes);
}

public static explicit operator int(Time t)
{
    return t.hours * 60 + t.minutes;
}
public static Time operator +(Time t1, int num)
{
    int total = t1.hh * 60 + t1.mm + num;
    int h = (int)(total / 60) % 24,
        m = total % 60;
    return new Time(h, m);
}

public int Minutes { get { return minutes; } set { minutes = value % 60; } }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Time t1 = new Time(9, 30);
        Time t2 = t1;
        t1.minutes = 100;
        Console.WriteLine("The time is: \nt1={0}  \nt2={1} ", t1, t2);
        Time t3 = t1 + 45;
    }
}
}
```

Good practice : `hours` and `minutes` variable should be `private` not `public`, if you are providing `getter` and `setter` for that.
I don't know your exact requirement but I think below code

```
public int Minutes { get { return minutes; } set { minutes = value % 60; } }
```

should get replaced with following :

```
public int Minutes { 
        get { return minutes; } 
        set {
            if (value > 60)
                hours = hours + (int)value / 60;
            minutes = value % 60; 
        } 
    }
```

hope this will help.

Comment: It did help. Thank you very much Bhushan.